# MySQL - Data Loading by Partitions, and Indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, partitioning

This is for MySQL 5.7 with InnoDB.

I have a partitioned table, and I'll be doing batch data loading (of a large amount of data) by partitions. i.e. I know that each batch of data I load will fall exclusively into one partition.

Now, the common way to handle indexes with data loading (as far as I know), would be to drop all indexes first, do the data loading, then re-create the indexes.

But I'm wondering, since I'm loading by partitions, is this still the most optimal way (dropping and then re-creating indexes) since it seems like I'm unnecessarily "touching" the non-updated partitions this way.

e.g.

1. Loading data into partition 1.

   1. Drop all indexes - nothing happens, since no data yet.
   2. Load data - all goes into partition 1.
   3. Create indexes - only parition 1 is modified.
2. Loading data into partition 2.

   1. Drop all indexes - all indexes in partition 1 dropped (unnecessary!)
   2. Load data - all goes into partition 2.
   3. Create indexes - partition 1 indexes re-created (unnecessary!) and partition 2 indexes created.
   4. And hence, loading this second batch of data takes significantly longer than the first batch. And it will get worse for each batch!

In that case, should I just pre-create the indexes and leave them there when loading data?

(BTW, don't worry about queries. The database is "offline" when data loading takes place. The objective here is only to shorten the time for each batch of data loading.)

The table schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ID      BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    YEAR    SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    MONTH   TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    A       CHAR(4),
    B       VARCHAR(127),
    C       VARCHAR(15),
    D       VARCHAR(511),
    E       TEXT,
    F       TEXT,
    G       VARCHAR(127),
    H       VARCHAR(127),
    I       VARCHAR(127),
    J       VARCHAR(511),
    K       VARCHAR(511),
    L       BIT(1),
    CONSTRAINT PKEY PRIMARY KEY (ID, YEAR, MONTH)
)
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(YEAR, MONTH) (
    PARTITION PART1 VALUES IN ((2007, 1)),
    PARTITION PART2 VALUES IN ((2007, 2)),
    PARTITION PART3 VALUES IN ((2007, 3)),
    ...
);
```

And, of course, there are a bunch of indexes (14 in all), mostly involving 2 to 4 columns. None of the 2 `TEXT` columns are in any of the index.

Comment: InnoDB?  What are the `SELECTs` like?  What indexes will you be adding?  utf8?  Is it actually beneficial to split `YEAR` and `MONTH` instead of using a single-column `DATE`?  Will the selects span more than one month?  Do you _always_ use `WHERE year=constant AND month=constant`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using InnoDB, do not drop the `PRIMARY KEY`.

All `PARTITIONs` always have the same indexes.  So you cannot turn on/off indexes separately.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further critique and advice.  I *may* say that `PARTITIONing` is of no use; there are very few use cases were it is worth using `PARTITION`.  [*More info, and use cases*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/)

Comment: For this table, I have time-based data. Each batch is a month of data. Partitioning would help with data aging (e.g. dropping of entire partition when some old data is no longer of use).

Understand that I can't have index by individual partition. Hence the question. Instead of dropping and re-creating index every time I load a batch of data, would it be better to leave the index there, so that whenever I load data, the other partitions need not be "touched" by dropping and creating index unnecessarily?

Comment: Oh, I'm not dropping the PRIMARY KEY... only the non-PK indexes.

Comment: I understand the question, but I don't have a direct answer.  I would like to see the indexes anyway.  That one use case is a very good one.  Another question:  How many rows in a 'batch'?

Comment: Edited the OP to add the table schema. There are ~20 million rows in each batch.

Comment: You would be better of batching 1000 rows at a time -- then `COMMIT` after each 1000.  The impact of trying to save 20M rows for `ROLLBACK` is significant.  What kind of data comes in 20M rows at a time??

Comment: sorry for not being clear. i do commit after every 10k rows. my question is actually at a higher level. i do data loading by lots (avoiding the word "batch" for clarity) of about 20M records. each lot will go exclusively into 1 partition. in terms of the indexes i have, should i still be dropping all indexes everytime i do data loading (of one lot) and then re-creating them after.

Comment: Since you can't recreate index(es) for a single partition, I expect it to be terribly slow.

Comment: "comment after 10K" -- Fine.  It _may_ help to sort the 20M by the PK before breaking into 10K pieces.